# HTTPS Force Redirect not working in Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My Wordpress directory is at www.example.com/blog

I recently changed my entire site to force HTTPS. So my .htaccess file in /blog/ looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I also changed the site URL in Wordpress settings to be HTTPS.

This works perfectly in the homepage, but in any post pages, the end user is able to change to non-secure HTTP, by changing the URL and pressing enter.

For example, they can type directly: http://www.example.com/blog/post-1/ and it will load as HTTP.

What is wrong with my .htaccess file? Where is the loose end?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change the order of the rules. First redirect to `https` and then let WP take over all of your requests.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I thought it was surely a syntax error in my `.htaccess` but sure enough it was WordPress rewrites coming first. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks for this. Also we should put it in a separate block, outside the wordpress declaration, to prevent wordpress from overriding this rules when we change the permalink settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add these two lines to the wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

So you could easily make conditions for http for dev environment and https for live like so:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'livedomain.com') !== FALSE){
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
  define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
} else {
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Recently we faced a similar problem, while we did everything as below:

1. Installed active SSL (with Green Padlock icon)
2. Updating Site Address in Admin Panel (Settings ’ General)
3. Putting the following code into the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But still, the site was not forced to HTTPS and both the HTTP and HTTPS were working independently.

We tried disabling all the plugins, clearing the cache, etc. with no luck.

## Solution

Then we just moved the above code snippet **above all the lines** in the `.htaccess`, and that worked for us.

```
# 1. HTTPS REDIRECTION CODE <----- ✅
# 2. WordPress Code
# 3. Any other htaccess directives
```