# Only Home Page Works in Wordpress https

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, ssl, https

Everything on my site looks good with http but I set up SSL and now http still looks good but https only works on the index page.  If I go anywhere else using https it says the page is not found on the server.

I tried this:
[HTTPS Force Redirect not working in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168489/https-force-redirect-not-working-in-wordpress)
but no success.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the link in Admin panel , settings->general, site address from http to https.

Also check your Apache settings.

Comment: I tried changing it to https as you suggested but that didn't work.  Can you be more specific when you say to check my apache settings?

Comment: For your ssl virtualhost, The settings should be  <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
Check allowoverride is all

Comment: Thanks! I had AllowOverride set to None instead of All, which was preventing the wordpress rewrite rules inside an htaccess file from working.